# Android browser not able to access router's settings page

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, browser

I can access the router's settings page via `192.168.1.1` with my PC but not with my android device. What can be the reason?

My device: `Android gingerbread` with stock browser. Also tried with other browsers. e.g. `Opera Mini`, etc..

**EDIT 1:**
My device is connected in the same network via wi-fi.
The IP's of different devices on the network are:

1. Home PC: 192.168.1.2
2. Router: 192.168.1.1
3. Android Device: 192.168.1.3

**EDIT 2: Screen-shots**

4. **Pinging stackoverflow**: IP is not static. Router assigns dynamically. Right now, the device is assigned 192.1

   [image: Pinging]
5. **Browser not able to load router's page:**

   [image: List item]

Comment: Are you sure, that your phone is connected to the same network as your pc and router? What is the IP of your phone? What error do you get in the browser?

Comment: Yup. The router page can be accessed in my office. But not in my home.

Comment: Can you Ping your Router from the Android device?

Comment: Yes. The internet works fine. Only the router can't be accessed.

Comment: Have you tried to literally enter 'http://192.168.1.1' (not just the IP alone)? Opera Mini cannot work because it can only display public accessible sites (opera.com is used as a proxy which does some preprocessing).

Comment: Yes. No luck with stock browser as well as opera mini.

Comment: Still the open question: What is the IP of your Android device then? Is your WiFi connection active (you might be on mobile data instead, which would explain your problem -- so please answer *both* questions)

Comment: Sounds like DNS on the handset does not know about the IP address, strange though because the router has allocated an ip address to your handset and can access the internet from there, unless, the access to  router is restricted by certain MAC addresses?

Comment: Are you sure that your wifi network is the same network at your wired network? Is this your home network or work? At my work, our wireless is not the same network as wired, in order to get on the same network I have to set up VPN on my phone.

Comment: @Izzy, Yes the device is connected to the same network.

Comment: @RyanConrad, I have only one router. It is an ADSL router (Home network). I can access the same router using 192.168.1.1 via laptops or desktops.

Comment: @najus and for the second time, you didn't answer the question (IP of your device). Might turn out interesting.

Comment: @Izzy, Sorry. But if the device is connected to the same network then isn't it obvious? It's 192.168.1.3

Comment: @najus It's obvious the other way around. Sorry for being that penetrant, but it wouldn't be the first time one insisted "I'm sure" -- and suddenly it turned out the IP said otherwise. So yes, now that you mentioned the IP explicitly, we all can be sure it is and base our thinking on it, thus eliminating a probable cause (and it implicitly gives proof your WiFi is switched on and working). Thanks for the update!

Comment: No problem @Izzy. Updated the question too.

Comment: @najus Good idea :) Might also be a good idea to name the different browsers you've tried (you already noticed from below answer why Opera cannot work; maybe other browsers have other specialities). I already upvoted your question for "research efford shown" ;)

Comment: i want to add that I think it is strange that the IP is 192.168.1.3. You set the IP static? Are you sure that you set up the correct DNS and Gateway then? I say that I think you did static because most "home" routers don't start DHCP addresses until ~192.168.1.51 to save some spots for static IPs.

Comment: @RyanConrad, IP is dynamically assigned. See edited question.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar behavior with my last Router I had (it was a DLINK Router), there was an option "do not Display Router Configuration Page for WiFi Devices".

This is just a possible option I can imagine now.

Opera Mini would generally not work, since it's traffic is routed over the Operas Servers to compress the Webtraffic that is been sent to your smartphone.

Quote:

> Unlike straightforward web browsers, Opera Mini fetches all content through a proxy server and reformats web pages into a format more suitable for small screens.[33] A page is compressed, then delivered to the phone in a markup language called OBML (Opera Binary Markup Language), which Opera Mini can interpret.[34] The data compression makes transfer time about two to three times faster,[18] and the pre-processing improves the display of web pages not designed for small screens.[35]

Source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mini

And since Opera isn't able to route into your private network it would not work.

Comment: I guess there's no option now.

Comment: Which router do you use?

Comment: I use Tenda router. http://www.tenda.cn/tendacn/product/show.aspx?productid=389

Comment: Is your PC connected wired to the network over Patch Cable?

Comment: No. Its connected via wi-fi.

Comment: Do your Android device display a Error loading the page or a blank screen? Have you tried pinging your Android Device from your PC? What is the IP Adress of your Android Smartphone and the IP Adress of the PC you are using in your local network. Internal IP Adress of your network?

Comment: It shows error like it is not connected to a network. But I can browse other pages without any problem. Yes I can ping my device from PC. The IP addresses are:
Phone: 192.168.1.3
PC: 192.168.1.2
Router: 192.168.1.1

Comment: Can you try accessing the Routers config page using    http://192.168.1.1:80 ?

Comment: I'll try it once I reach home.